# Disable ipv4/ipv6 programmatically

Tags: linux, network-programming

Is it possible to disable/enable ipv4/ipv6 functionality programmatically on linux? By disabling ipv4 I mean that the system should not respond to or initiate any ipv4 traffic. And enabling ipv4 will have the system respond to ipv4 traffic.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just disallow it using iptables?

Comment: @MattJoiner: because that goes against the spirit of the question. The OP is asking how to disable ipv4/6 at a syscall level, I'm asking if it's really necessary to muck around at that level when a firewall could be configured to (effectively) perform the same function. I'm offering an alternative point of view.

Comment: @Chris: Show how to do it programmatically using iptables...

Comment: @MattJoiner: as strange as this may sound, I don't know how. That's why I put it in as a comment and not an answer. I know iptables *can* do it, not *how* to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could just delete your IPv4 IP address and it makes it impossible for your system to participate in IPv4 traffic.  To re-enable it, just add the address back.  Same applies for IPv6.

Checkout iproute2 (`/sbin/ip addr help`) command and friends.  To display your addresses run `ip addr ls`.  IPv4 address start on a line with `inet` and IPv6 address lines start with `inet6`

Comment: Yes. If you have no IPv4 address on the interface, you can't use IP4. Likewise IPv6 (although this is more tricky because of auto-assignment)